# magento appends a querystring parameter to CSS and JS

Tags: css, xml, magento, query-string

How Can I  appends a querystring parameter to each CSS and JavaScript include in the HTML to clear CSS and JavaScript cache. 
I have tried

> `<action
>   method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/style.css?123</stylesheet></action>`

and

> `<action
>   method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles.css?123</name><params/></action>`

.
But each time it returns a the base package like

> `http://www.example.com/skin/frontend/base/default/styles.css?123`

not my custom theme directory .

How to solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're adding a css file through xml layout updates, the `addCss` action (which realy just calls the `addItem` action with the type set to `skin_css`) is looking for a file path, not a url.  While query strings are valid in urls, they aren't in file names.  Magento sees that as an invalid parameter, gets confused and falls back to `base/default`.

I can think of 2 solutions for this.  Unfortunately both are kind of hackey.

1. Move the css file to the base default theme.  This works but it depends on fallbacks that might not stay the same in other versions of magento.
2. instead of directly inserting the css file, create a phtml template file with the html code to insert a css file.  Then insert a `core/template` block with that new template file as its template in the layout xml.  I've used this method on the sites i develop for to work around this problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will try the second solution, but still wait another alternative.

Answer (score 4):

This free extension should do what you want - works perfectly for me:

https://github.com/jreinke/magento-suffix-static-files

Answer (score 1):

Here's what we do:

```
<reference name="head">
   <block type="core/text" name="link.tags">
      <action method="setText">
        <text>
           <![CDATA[<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css?v=2">]]>
        </text>
      </action>
   </block>
</reference>
```

Got this idea along with some other useful stuff from [5 Useful Tricks For Your Magento local.xml](http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/5-useful-tricks-for-your-magento-local-xml/).

As an alternative, you can always just rename the file from `style_v1.css` to `style_v2.css` etc. whenever you make a change -- it has the same effect as changing `style.css?v=1` to `style.css?v=2`.

Answer (score 0):

as a follow up answer to this question i found the following (paid) magento extension which does what you require:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/clear-css-and-javascript-cache.html